# SQL Server 2008 - Group Users By Device

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

In my Database I have a table named devices with the following structure:

```
Id (PK)
Username
DeviceID
Device_type
Date_Registered
```

I'm struggling to form a query which will retrieve usernames which have more than just one device_type and listing them X times (where X is the amount of device_types they have).

The final list would have to be ordered by Username and showing some like the following:

```
foo@foo | ipad |
foo@foo | android |
foo2@foo | iphone |
foo2@foo | ipad |
```

Could anyone help me finding the right way to achieve this?

And also if you're helping, please explain more or less the logic behind it because I really struggle when it comes to group by and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinct keyword will only give you the unique combinations of Username and Device_type:

```
select distinct Username, Device_type from yourtable
```

This is the same as:

```
select Username, Device_type from yourtable group by Username, Device_type
```

Group by would be useful if you would like to count the devices per username and device_type for example:

```
select Username, Device_type, count(*) as device_count from yourtable group by Username, Device_type
```

**EDIT**

I misunderstood you question. To get list of users who have more than one device type is a bit more difficult but still straightforward. The key is the `HAVING` cluase where you select only those usernames which have more than one device type assigned.

```
select distinct Username, Device_type from yourtable
where username in 
(
    -- get list of users with more than one device type
    select username from yourtable
    group by username
    having count(distinct device_type) > 1
)
order by username
```

Comment: Hey TomT, thanks for your answer. This query won't do what I need, because I should only return the usernames which have more than one device, and those devices should be different between each other. I.e., it should not return usernames with 3 ipads, but only usernames which may have an ipad and another different device.

Comment: @Hallaghan you are right, please see updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot man, it helped me to understand the problem and solved the question.